# Connecting TextWatcher with custom adapter to filter text through EditText

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

I am pretty new to Android development and I have wrote some codes with the help of an example from a website about a custom `ListView`, now with the `ListView` I want to attach an `EditText` that filter the text and displays in the `ListView` only what I wrote.

Currently, when I type anything the `ListView` gets blank and nothing shows, but when I delete my input, the `ListView` restores with original items.

This is my adapter class:

```
public class EntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

     private Context context;
     private ArrayList<Item> items;
     private LayoutInflater vi;
     public Context conx;

     public EntryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
          super(context,0, items);
          this.context = context;
          this.items = items;
          vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     }
```

And this is my insertion of data for the `main-class`

```
  items.add(new SectionItem("letters"));
  items.add(new EntryItem("a","subtitle","image"));
  items.add(new EntryItem("b","subtitle","image"));
```

And this is my `textWatcher`, a simple one that I have created:

```
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text
        StartClass.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

And here applying the `adapter` and setting `listview`

```
EntryAdapter adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items);
x = adapter;
  listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? I have tried to watch couple of tutorials but none where as good to show me how to implement it, I implemented it but it doesn't work. Any ideas what I might be missing..?

Comment: sorry im updating the question,  i submitted by mistake .. plz wait a minute

Comment: What is `StartClass.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(*)`

Comment: sorry for being late, this is normal applying the filteration to the adapter. the * is the characters depending on the parameter which is in mine cs. @JuanCortes